# Making a second address in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the code:

```
class VendorProfile(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Address2 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Is there a better way to do address line2? The reason I have address2 is because some apartments have the extra line of an address. Is there a better way to do this? I just need some thinking power, as I feel like I could be doing this a better way.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me. Only other way I could image would be to make `Address` a `TextArea`, and allow a user to enter multiple lines.

Comment: So I would just do it as address.models.TextField(max_length=256) and that would allow multiple lines?

Comment: If you want to make things more explicit, [take a look here](https://github.com/iiilx/django-addressbook/blob/master/addressbook/models.py#L90)

Comment: Your example isn't enough @karthikr. I can't write my full address with only fields exposed in this application... Where do I write my appartment number, and other strangeness of a French address (CS, Cedex, etc.)

Comment: It would be better if you used `lower_case_with_underscores` for your field names, but I suppose that's now what you meant... :/

Comment: @MaximeLorant I said take a look here (to get an idea)